# How to make test file names appear in Gitlab Junit test report?

Tags: angular, junit, gitlab-ci, karma-runner, test-reporting

I installed `karma-junit-reporter` in an angular project with the following settings:

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        failSpecWithNoExpectations: true,
      }
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'reports', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      outputFile: 'junit.xml', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
      useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
      // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
      nameFormatter: function(browser, result) {
        return result.description;
      },
      // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
      classNameFormatter: function(browser, result) {
        return result.suite[0];
      },
      properties: {}, // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
      xmlVersion: null // use '1' if reporting to be per SonarQube 6.2 XML format
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', "ChromeHeadlessCI"],
    singleRun: false,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessCI: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    }
  });
};
```

When the `unit-tests` job runs in the Gitlab pipeline:

```yaml
unit_tests:
  stage: test
  needs:
    - job: app_build
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
    - apt install -y ./google-chrome*.deb;
  variables:
    CHROME_BIN: /usr/bin/google-chrome
  script:
    - npm link @angular/cli@11.2.19
    - npm run test -- --no-watch --no-progress --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI
  cache:
    - key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-node_modules
      paths:
        - .npm/
        - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit:
        - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/src/reports/*.xml
  allow_failure: true
```

The reports are generated, but the field with the file name does not appear:
[image]

Does anyone who also use `karma-junit-reporter` know how to add this information to reports?

Comment: Please could you add the image directly in the question?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. Now it's updated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `karma-junit-reporter` but had the same problem. The JUnit XML output seems to be missing some attributes. Make sure that the `testcase` tags have an attribute `file`, e.g. `<testcase id="1" name="your-test-name" file="yourfile" ...>`